# how I can access the global variable and not the parameter value?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to access the variable with the "apfala"

```
var frucht="apfala";
function getFrucht(frucht){
console.log(frucht);
console.log(this.frucht) // I want here the apfala one, I thought .this would work
}
getFrucht("apfel");
```

Or do I have to rename them differently?

Comment: you can use `window.frutch` to access the global. But not a best practice to have the same name

Comment: Are you running this code in strict mode? Otherwise that should have worked.

Comment: I know that it might not be the best question in the universe, but I'm pretty sure that no one is learning anything from downvoting without explaining why...

Comment: well, I thought I would get answer I can use for NodeJs too .-. since I cannot use window there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-shadow

> Shadowing is the process by which a local variable shares the same
>   name as a variable in its containing scope. For example:
>
> ```
> var a = 3;
> function b() {
>     var a = 10;
> }
> ```
>
> In this case, the variable a inside of b() is shadowing the variable a
>   in the global scope. This can cause confusion while reading the code
>   and it’s impossible to access the global variable.

Your code suggests that you need to rethink whatever it is you are trying to do. As it is unclear as to the true nature of what you are trying to do, it is hard to suggest an alternative solution to your problem (other than do not shadow or use globals), if you have one rather than just curiosity?

Please don't do this, but this should work in all environments.

```js
'use strict';

var getGlobal = Function('return this');

getGlobal().frucht = 'apfala';

function getFrucht(frucht) {
  console.log(frucht);
  console.log(getGlobal().frucht); // I want here the apfala one, I thought .this would work
}

getFrucht('apfe');
```

Also see: https://www.npmjs.com/package/system.global

Answer (score 1):

In case your javascript runs in a browser, you can use the `window` global variable in order to access the variable `frucht` that defined in the global scope:

```js
var frucht="apfala";
function getFrucht(frucht){
  console.log(frucht);
  console.log(window.frucht) // I want here the apfala one, I thought .this would work
}
getFrucht("apfel");
```

Answer (score 1):

If it is a global **and** you are running in a browser:

You can use `window.frucht` as global variables are properties of the `window` object.

Not reusing the same variable name would be a much better idea though. It avoids the dependency on globals and the confusing of reusing names.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, in JavaScript, if you want to pass a parent scope to a child one, you need to assign `this` in the parent to a variable and access that variable inside the child:

```
var frucht="apfala";
var parent = this;
function getFrucht(frucht){
  console.log(frucht);
  console.log(parent.frucht);
}
getFrucht("apfel");
```

Also, as stated in other answers, if you are working in a browser, just use the `window` object to attach and access global variables (`window.frucht="apfala"`, then use `window.frucht` to access that variable)

Hope that helps.